# DatePicker [eyecon] remove no of weeks

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using eyecon [Datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/) plugin.

Plugin is great but i want to remove Number of weeks showing on left side.

[image]

here is my code

```
(function($){
    var initLayout2 = function() {
        $('#date3').DatePicker({
            flat: true,
            date: ['2009-12-28','2010-01-23'],
            current: '2010-01-01',
            calendars: 3,
            mode: 'range',
            starts: 1,
        });
    };
    EYE.register(initLayout2, 'init');
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to edit the js and the css files.

For datepicker.css replace class div.datepicker **width: 176px** instead of 196px.

datepicker.js file

```
tpl = {
            wrapper: '<div class="datepicker"><div class="datepickerBorderT" /><div class="datepickerBorderB" /><div class="datepickerBorderL" /><div class="datepickerBorderR" /><div class="datepickerBorderTL" /><div class="datepickerBorderTR" /><div class="datepickerBorderBL" /><div class="datepickerBorderBR" /><div class="datepickerContainer"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr></tr></tbody></table></div></div>',
            head: [
                '<td>',
                '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">',
                    '<thead>',
                        '<tr>',
                            '<th class="datepickerGoPrev"><a href="#"><span><%=prev%></span></a></th>',
                            '<th colspan="5" class="datepickerMonth"><a href="#"><span></span></a></th>',
                            '<th class="datepickerGoNext"><a href="#"><span><%=next%></span></a></th>',
                        '</tr>',
                        '<tr class="datepickerDoW">',
                            //'<th><span><%=week%></span></th>',
                            '<th><span><%=day1%></span></th>',
                            '<th><span><%=day2%></span></th>',
                            '<th><span><%=day3%></span></th>',
                            '<th><span><%=day4%></span></th>',
                            '<th><span><%=day5%></span></th>',
                            '<th><span><%=day6%></span></th>',
                            '<th><span><%=day7%></span></th>',
                        '</tr>',
                    '</thead>',
                '</table></td>'
            ],
            space : '<td class="datepickerSpace"><div></div></td>',
            days: [
                '<tbody class="datepickerDays">',
                    '<tr>',
                        //'<th class="datepickerWeek"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[0].week%></span></a></th>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[0].days[0].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[0].days[0].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[0].days[1].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[0].days[1].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[0].days[2].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[0].days[2].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[0].days[3].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[0].days[3].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[0].days[4].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[0].days[4].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[0].days[5].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[0].days[5].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[0].days[6].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[0].days[6].text%></span></a></td>',
                    '</tr>',
                    '<tr>',
                        //'<th class="datepickerWeek"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[1].week%></span></a></th>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[1].days[0].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[1].days[0].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[1].days[1].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[1].days[1].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[1].days[2].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[1].days[2].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[1].days[3].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[1].days[3].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[1].days[4].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[1].days[4].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[1].days[5].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[1].days[5].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[1].days[6].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[1].days[6].text%></span></a></td>',
                    '</tr>',
                    '<tr>',
                        //'<th class="datepickerWeek"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[2].week%></span></a></th>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[2].days[0].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[2].days[0].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[2].days[1].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[2].days[1].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[2].days[2].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[2].days[2].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[2].days[3].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[2].days[3].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[2].days[4].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[2].days[4].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[2].days[5].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[2].days[5].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[2].days[6].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[2].days[6].text%></span></a></td>',
                    '</tr>',
                    '<tr>',
                        //'<th class="datepickerWeek"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[3].week%></span></a></th>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[3].days[0].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[3].days[0].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[3].days[1].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[3].days[1].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[3].days[2].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[3].days[2].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[3].days[3].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[3].days[3].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[3].days[4].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[3].days[4].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[3].days[5].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[3].days[5].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[3].days[6].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[3].days[6].text%></span></a></td>',
                    '</tr>',
                    '<tr>',
                        //'<th class="datepickerWeek"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[4].week%></span></a></th>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[4].days[0].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[4].days[0].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[4].days[1].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[4].days[1].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[4].days[2].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[4].days[2].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[4].days[3].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[4].days[3].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[4].days[4].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[4].days[4].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[4].days[5].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[4].days[5].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[4].days[6].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[4].days[6].text%></span></a></td>',
                    '</tr>',
                    '<tr>',
                        //'<th class="datepickerWeek"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[5].week%></span></a></th>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[5].days[0].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[5].days[0].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[5].days[1].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[5].days[1].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[5].days[2].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[5].days[2].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[5].days[3].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[5].days[3].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[5].days[4].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[5].days[4].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[5].days[5].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[5].days[5].text%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td class="<%=weeks[5].days[6].classname%>"><a href="#"><span><%=weeks[5].days[6].text%></span></a></td>',
                    '</tr>',
                '</tbody>'
            ],
            months: [
                '<tbody class="<%=className%>">',
                    '<tr>',
                        '<td colspan="2"><a href="#"><span><%=data[0]%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td colspan="2"><a href="#"><span><%=data[1]%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td colspan="2"><a href="#"><span><%=data[2]%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td colspan="2"><a href="#"><span><%=data[3]%></span></a></td>',
                    '</tr>',
                    '<tr>',
                        '<td colspan="2"><a href="#"><span><%=data[4]%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td colspan="2"><a href="#"><span><%=data[5]%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td colspan="2"><a href="#"><span><%=data[6]%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td colspan="2"><a href="#"><span><%=data[7]%></span></a></td>',
                    '</tr>',
                    '<tr>',
                        '<td colspan="2"><a href="#"><span><%=data[8]%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td colspan="2"><a href="#"><span><%=data[9]%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td colspan="2"><a href="#"><span><%=data[10]%></span></a></td>',
                        '<td colspan="2"><a href="#"><span><%=data[11]%></span></a></td>',
                    '</tr>',
                '</tbody>'
            ]
        },
```

Comment %week% and %weeks% variables, and replace colspan="5" instead of colspan="6" from datepickerMonth.